# Вопрос по wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

После установки плагина Qtranslate X при добавлние или обновлении любой страницы админка вылетает в белый экран. Кроме этого не видны загруженные медиафайлы. С чем это может быть связано и как это можно исправить?

Comment: если не отображаются загруженные файлы, возможно ваши файлы содержать кириллические символы. пробелы, и.тд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорей всего страница отдает сообщение о нехватке ресурса, но режим вывода ошибок выключен в настройках php вашего сервера по этому вы видите белый лист. Лог поможет это прояснить. Смотреть в сторону нехватки памяти, ограничений на исполнение скриптов.